# image as a hyperlink in cshtml

Tags: html, razor

How to make the logo a hyper link in chtml file when a user clicks on it I need it to go to http://mywebsite.com/ and would like to shrink the size of the image.

Trying to translate this to

```html
<img id="img_logo" alt="Logo" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/myImage.jpeg")" />
```

the one below.

```html
@Html.ActionLink("http://mywebsite.com/", <img id="img_logo" alt="Logo" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/myImage.jpeg")" />)
```

Comment: Wrap your image inside an a tag

Comment: `<a href="https;//www.google.com"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/myImage.jpeg")"></a>`

Comment: @Shyju Works...Thank you.